# VS2010/Intel Fortran doesn't find mulitiply defined symbols

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, fortran, intel-fortran

Background: We're using very old Fortran code (F77) developed originally on VAX/OpenVMS, which allowed for customized linking - i.e. you could define multiple symbols in your library, but were given the ability to force the linker to use a specific symbol.

Using VS2010 and Intel Fortran 2013, I am looking for a way for the linker to force it to use the symbol (i.e. MYSUBROUTINE) from a specific library when it exists in mutiple libraries.

I have a mixed C++/Fortran project. The in-house developed libraries are not my own, so removing the unused subroutine isn't trivial. Hence, why I'm looking for a way to force the VS2010/Intel Fortran 2013 linker to use a specific subroutine.

I imagine this issue isn't unique to us, since many legacy code houses, particularly ones with alot of Fortran, must have this issue.

Comment: I should that the root cause of the issue is that the linker **never**  finds the multiply defined symbols even if I exclude the /FORCE:MULTIPLE option, and it always creates an .exe anyways - but its random as to whether the .exe will execute or has an image problem. Thus, being able to control which Subroutine is used in the image is huge. Any advice on how to get it to find a mutiply defined symbol that you know is there would also be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When searching libraries (.lib), the linker will use the first matching symbol that it finds.  Libraries are searched in a well defined order.  To have a different library take precedence for a particular symbol, specify the library earlier in the link command line (list it earlier in Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies for the executable project within Visual Studio)

If you have multiple subroutines across multiple libraries that you want chosen, then you will need to use a different approach, such as unpacking the libraries and selecting the object code for the routines that you want as a separate step.

Note that object files take precedence over libraries when searching for symbols.

Multiply defined symbols only applies to symbols within object files (.obj).